# Set validation for multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to validate `FileUpload` control for check that user can select only 10 images. I already have the server-side code. But i want to validate it on client side.

**Code:**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" CssClass="myButton1" multiple="multiple" 
     runat="server"  />
<asp:Button ID="Btnuploadimages" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" 
     Style="margin-top: 2px;"  OnClientClick="return ValidateFile2()" 
     Text="Upload" OnClick="Btnuploadimages_Click" />
```

Comment: using Jquery https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options and check for `data.files.length`

Answer (score 0):

In Your `ValidateFile2()` Method you need to add the below code so that you can get the `selected files count` from the `File Upload Control`. You can validate the selected files count by checking the below conditions.

**Client Side Code :** `JavaScript`

```
function ValidateFile2(){
    var fileCount = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files.length;
    if(fileCount > 10) // Selected images with in 10 count
    {
       alert("Please select only 10 images..!!!");
       return false;
    }
    else if(fileCount <= 0) // Selected atleast 1 image check
    {
       alert("Please select atleat 1 image..!!!");
       return false;
    }

    return true;  // Good to go
}
```

**JQuery** and **Javascript** code is available on my work out in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvLAc/93/)